The DFL request failed with status 'InternalServerError
I'm facing an issue with the TwilioSMS connector in Power Automate Desktop. I'm trying to send SMS messages, but I keep getting the following error:
The strange thing is that the same connector works perfectly fine when I use it in a Cloud Flow.
I'm quite new to Power Automate Desktop, so I'm a bit lost on how to troubleshoot this. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Additional info:
{
  "StatusCode": "500",
  "Message": "",
  "Body": {
    "error": {
      "code": "InternalServerError",
      "message": "Http request failed with unhandled exception of type 'NullReferenceException' and message: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'."
    }
  },

Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Robin.Connectors.Execution.ConnectorInternalErrorException: The DFL request failed with status 'InternalServerError'.
   at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Robin.Engine.Execution.Connectors.CloudConnectorRequestHandler.<HandleErrorResponse>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Robin.Engine.Execution.Connectors.CloudConnectorRequestHandler.<ExecuteHttpRequest>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Robin.Engine.Execution.Connectors.CloudConnectorRequestHandler.<Execute>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Robin.Engine.Execution.Connectors.CloudConnectorRunner.<>c__DisplayClass34_1.<<Run>b__1>d.MoveNext()


PA and PAD are completely different products, to say it's the "same connector" would be grossly incorrect.  My suggestion, make a call from PAD to PA and use that cloud flow to send your SMS, safer and a lot more stable.
